# Atmega328 ubrr value shifting issue for serial transmission

Tags: atmega, uart, atmega328p, baudrate

My doubt is about the way in which the baudrate value is written into UBRRn registers.

For eg:

Lets say i want to write the value 25 into UBBRn registers to configure the microcontroller to communicate at a particular baud rate.

I use the following code to do that

```
unsigned int ubrr = 25; // 0000 0000 0001 1001 (16 bit binary representation)

UBRR0H = (ubrr>>8);     // Moving the lower Byte 0001 1001 to UBRR0H 
UBRR0L = (ubrr);        // Moving  0000 0000 to UBRR0L
```

Why are we moving the lower byte to the high register UBRR0H and the higher byte to UBRR0L (after shifting).

Generally when we are moving a 16 bit value to two 8 bit registers,

- The Lower byte will be moved to the Lower register (UBRR0L) and
- Higher byte will be moved to the High register (UBRR0H)

Why is ATmega328p reversing this trend,

Is this a design issue,or there is any specific reason to do this ?

Also UBBR0H has only 4 bits and the upper nibble will be discarded ?

I would like to point out the default code in the datasheet is working perfectly for me,I am just curious why it is done like that?

Answer (score 1):

> Why are we moving the lower byte to the high register UBRR0H and the higher byte to UBRR0L (after shifting).

You aren't.

`ubrr >> 8` takes the upper 8 bits of `ubrr` and shifts them into the lower 8 bits, where they are written to `UBRR0H`. It doesn't modify the value of `ubrr`.

Writing a 16-bit value, like `ubrr`, to an 8-bit register, like `UBRR0L`, truncates the value to its lower 8 bits.